# Set background color of NSView with negative bounds origin

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, drawrect

I am currently trying to set a background color/pattern for an NSView that has a negative bounds origin. The problem is, that it only colors parts of the view (those where x>0 && y>0).

I understand, that I have to draw the background in the -(void)drawRect: function. How can I color the whole view, not just those parts where the coordinates are positive?

[image: NSView]
Origin: -65, -65
Size: 130, 130

I want to color the whole background

Comment: Which part of that is the view that's not drawing its whole background, and where is it in the view hierarchy?

Comment: I have an NSScrollView inside of which there is a Subclass of NSView. The Circle in the middle of the picture is an NSImageView, which is a subview of the NSView subclass.
I can display subviews in the negative areas, but no background is drawn. What I did right now is that I created another NSView with the same Size and put it as a subview. While it is not what I imagined, it solves my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `NSBezierPath` object to set the background colour of your view :

```
NSColor *color; //your background colour
CustomView *view; //this is your view, you should init it with the his own class
[color set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:[view bounds]]; //sets the given Rect with the set colour
```

This code should colour all the background with the given colour.
Note that you should replace the last line with `[path fillRect:[self bounds]]` if the code is in the implementation of the class of your view.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. There is no instance method fillRect: for NSBezierPath. And if i use [NSBezierPath fillRect:[self bounds]]; I still have the same Problem.

Comment: Yeah you're right it's a class method. Then try to create an `NSRect` with the properties of your view (same origin, width and height) and then call the `-fillRect` method with this rect.